# Clone/Mimic selection range

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, rangy

Selection does exactly what I need: Set a selection while the TTS reads the part, highlight the next part, and so on... the kicker is: The user must be able to change the selection color. I can set this in css through `::selection`, but I'm unable to change it while the extension is running. The selection color also blends with the word highlighting color within, changing z-index in css doesn't change this blending.

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

To circumvent this, I have written following code which sets begin and end of the range to mimic this behaviour but with full (color) control, although when applying the style to the parentElement of every node, in some cases, it will apply to a div or p, highlighting a whole portion of the text instead of the sentence:
(Don't mind the sentence algorithm, it's of no importance right now)

```
//Start a range for the highlighting
let range = rangy.createRange();
//Set the range on the first element with an offSet of 0
range.setStart(document.getElementById('ali' + i), 0);

while (
    document.getElementById('ali' + i) !== null) {

    let element = document.getElementById('ali' + i);

    senArray.push(element.innerText);
    wordIdArray.push(i);

    if (
        element.innerText.indexOf('.') >= 0
        || element.innerText.indexOf('?') >= 0
        || element.innerText.indexOf('!') >= 0
    ) {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

//Set the end of the range by getting the last element and its last offSet
let endOffset = document.getElementById('ali' + i).childNodes.length;
range.setEnd(document.getElementById('ali' + i), endOffset);

console.log(range);

//get nodes from range and apply style to parent element
let nodes = range.getNodes();
nodes.forEach(function (el) {
    el.parentNode("style", "background-color: " + readingUnitColor + ";")
});
//Make selection object, remove existing ranges (to be sure) and add the range to the selection object.
// let selection = window.getSelection();
// selection.removeAllRanges();
// selection.addRange(range);
```

I'm using rangy here, but I had the same results with native JS by using:

```
let CAContainer = range.commonAncestorContainer;
CAContainer.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + readingUnitColor + ";");
```

I also tried wrapping the sentences in a span, but whenever I add `'<span id="id">'` to the setStart part of the range, chrome will auto-close that tag immediately after the first node, regardless of `'</span>'` being at the setEnd of the range.

Any help or input will be kindly appreciated !